# Connect to Azure File Share from Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-cloud-shell

I don't know how to connect to an existing Azure File Share from Azure Cloud Shell.

The command `clouddrive` seems to move my default cloud shell storage account. But I don't want to do that. I just want to access my existing Azure File Share storage. This can exist in any Azurea region (not just what's available for Cloud Shell, which is currently very limited)

When I tried to use `clouddrive` to mount my existing Azure Files account, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: The storage account is not in the valid location. Expect: eastus Actual: canadacentral
```

I'd prefer not to move my existing Azure File Shares from `canadacentral` to `eastus`. Is there a workaround for this?

I'd like to just connect to my existing Azure File Shares through Cloud Shell and run commands in those directories.

Thank you!

---

Same question asked here:

- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42001
- https://serverfault.com/questions/992834/connect-to-azure-file-share-from-azure-cloud-shell

Answer (score 1):

Azure cloud shell is an interactive, authenticated, browser-accessible shell which backend is running on cloud shell hosts. The cloud shell machines are temporary but your files are persisted through a mounted file share named `clouddrive`.

By using the advanced option, you can [associate existing resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage#use-existing-resources). Also, the associated Azure storage accounts must reside in the same region as the Cloud Shell machine that you're mounting them to. To find your current region you may run `env` in Bash and locate the variable `ACC_LOCATION`. 
[image]

As the document stated, the `canadacentral` is not an available region for Cloud Shell, you should mount file storage in the available region. If so, you can run `clouddrive unmount` to unmount the current file share then select the existing file storage in the available region via clicking **advanced** settings in the initial login.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Nancy, this is all known to me. I don't want to use my `canadacentral` storage account for CloudShell. I just want to connect to a storage account in `cc` and execute commands in my Azure Files Share (or any NFS accessible through internet, e.g. Azure NetApp Files). I have files that are zipped in my Azure File Share in `cc` and I'd like to unzip them through cloud shell. I know there are workarounds, I'd just like to learn if what I want to do is possible.

Comment: Since you're not able to mount an existing file share due to the storage account region, you can copy files from an existing file share to your current `clouddrive` then unzip it in the cloud shell, then copy back to your existing file share. But it is complicated. I think the easiest way is to download and unzip and upload to your file share on the Azure portal.

Comment: You can use `az storage file upload` or `download` or `copy` commands with Azure CLI. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-cli#upload-a-file).

Comment: Do you need further help in your question?

Comment: Thanks @Nancy. This is another known workaround. But it doesn't address the core problem. For Linux Azure Cloud Shell session, I don't have access to `sudo`. But is there a way to mount a regular internet-accessible NFS drive? I feel that if I can do that in Az Cloud Shell then I can find a way to mount my existing Azure Files Share under my `canadacentral` storage account. I'm also open to using PowerShell Az Cloud Shell. I just can't figure out how to connect to an arbitrary NFS without root/admin privilege.

Comment: I tried and I also couldn't figure it out. As far as I know, I only have full control in my $HOME directory and do not have access to `sudo` in Azure cloud shell.